# Using react-cropper to crop my image. Before cropping image file size was 2mb, after 6mb

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cropperjs

```
const getCropData2 = () => {
        if (typeof cropperRef2.current?.cropper !== 'undefined') {
            const cropper = cropperRef2.current?.cropper;
            if ((cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL().length * (3/4)) / 1024 < 2048) FitnessStore.editFitnessImagesUpload({image: cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL()});
            else {
                FitnessStore.editFitnessImagesUpload({image: null});
                alert('Размер файла превышает 2 мб');
            }
            setImage2(true);
            handleClose2();
        }
    };
```

```
<Dialog
                open={open2}
                onClose={handleClose2}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
            >
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                        {!image2 && FitnessStore.fitnessImagesUpload.image ? <>
                            <Cropper
                                aspectRatio={10 / 11}
                                style={{height: 400}}
                                preview=".img-preview"
                                guides={true}
                                src={FitnessStore.fitnessImagesUpload.image}
                                ref={cropperRef2}
                                dragMode={'move'}
                                background={false}
                                responsive={true}
                                autoCropArea={1}
                                checkOrientation={false}
                                viewMode={1}
                                minCropBoxHeight={10}
                                minCropBoxWidth={10}
                            />
                        </> : null}
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={getCropData2}>Обрезать</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
```

Here is my Cropper component and ref to control proccess after cropping.
After the posting my image to cropper in some cases images get larger than it was before copping.
How to fix it? I need a file less than 2mb

Comment: You can reduce the file size and ensure that it remains below 2MB by compressing the cropped image before saving it.

Comment: @DavidTeo In case that original file more than 2mb, user should be able to crop and reduce it to 2mb. This is a customer requirement

Comment: @DavidTeo also original file is less than 2mb, but after cropping become larger and backend do not accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
cropperRef.current?.cropper
 .getCroppedCanvas()
 .toDataURL("image/jpeg")
```

This piece of code was helpful for me. Try to specify the mime type.